# Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

## Context: I've developed a button that appears on the product page of my nopcommerce store, and in the button it makes an AJAX request to the controller of my plugin, sending the name and price of the product so that my controller can migrate it to a table in the database. But when I try to make the request, I get this error

Response: Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating Nop.Plugin.Widgets.Samurai.Controller.SamuraiDataBaseMigrationController.
---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Nop.Plugin.Widgets.Samurai.Controller.SamuraiDataBaseMigrationController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Nop.Plugin.Widgets.Samurai.Interfaces.IProductInfoService productInfoService' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Nop.Plugin.Widgets.Samurai.Interfaces.IProductInfoService, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[Nop.Plugin.Widgets.Samurai.Controller.SamuraiDataBaseMigrationController])'. at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<UseSingleConstructorActivation>b__0(ResolveRequestContext ctxt, Action`1 next)
at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.DisposalTrackingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)

```
  [Authorize]
  public class SamuraiDataBaseMigrationController : BasePluginController
  {
      private readonly IProductInfoService _productInfoService;
      private readonly ILogger<SamuraiDataBaseMigrationController> _logger;
     
      public SamuraiDataBaseMigrationController(
          IProductInfoService productInfoService,
          ILogger<SamuraiDataBaseMigrationController> logger)
      {

          _productInfoService = productInfoService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(productInfoService));
          _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
          _logger.LogInformation($"SamuraiDataBaseMigrationController constructor - ProductInfoService: {_productInfoService.GetType().Name}");
      }


      [HttpPost]

      public ActionResult AdicionarAoMigrate([FromBody] ProductInfoModel productInfo)
      {
          if (productInfo == null)
          {
              _logger.LogError("ProductInfoModel is null.");
              return Json(new { success = false, message = "ProductInfoModel is null." });
          }

          try
          {
              _logger.LogInformation($"Iniciando AdicionarAoMigrate - productName: {productInfo.ProductName}, productPrice: {productInfo.PriceValue}");

              //MIGRANDO DADOS PARA A DATABASE  
              _productInfoService.MigrateProduct(productInfo);

              _logger.LogInformation("Informações do produto migradas com sucesso!");

              return Json(new { success = true, message = "Informações do produto migradas com sucesso!" });
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              _logger.LogError($"Erro ao processar a solicitação: {ex.Message}");
              return Json(new { success = false, message = $"Erro ao processar a solicitação: {ex.Message}" });
          }
      }
  }

 public static class AutofacConfig
 {
     public static IContainer ConfigureAutofac(IConfiguration configuration)
     {
         var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

         builder.RegisterType<SamuraiMigration>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

         builder.RegisterType<ProductInfo>().As<IProductInfoService>().InstancePerDependency();
        
         builder.RegisterType<SamuraiDataBaseMigrationController>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

         builder.RegisterType<Logger<SamuraiDataBaseMigrationController>>().As<ILogger<SamuraiDataBaseMigrationController>>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();


         return builder.Build();
     }
 }

  public interface IProductInfoService
  {
      void MigrateProduct(ProductInfoModel product);

      void InsertProductInfo(string productName, decimal productPrice);


 public class ProductInfo : IProductInfoService
 {
     private readonly IDataContext _dataContext;
  
     
     

     public ProductInfo(IDataContext dataContext)
     {
         _dataContext = dataContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataContext));
      
        
     }

     public void MigrateProduct(ProductInfoModel product)
     {
         _dataContext.Insert(product);
     }

     public void InsertProductInfo(string productName, decimal productPrice)
     {
         var productInfo = new ProductInfoModel
         {
             ProductName = productName,
             PriceValue = productPrice
         };

         _dataContext.Insert(productInfo);
     }

    
 }

@if (!Model.DisableMigrateButton)

{
    <div class="add-to-migrate-button">
        <button class="add-to-migrate" id="add-to-migrate" type="button">ADD TO BASE</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#add-to-migrate").click(function () {
                var productName = $(".product-name").text();
                var prices = parseFloat($(".product-price").text().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''));
                console.log("URL:", '@Url.RouteUrl("AddProductToBase")');


                armazenarDadosNoBanco(productName,prices);
            });

            function armazenarDadosNoBanco(productName,prices) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.RouteUrl("AddProductToBase")',
                    cache: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        productName: productName,
                        productPrice: prices
                    }),
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.info("Successful data migration")
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        console.error("AJAX request error:", error);
                        console.error("Status:", status);
                        console.error("Response:", xhr.responseText);
                    }
                    
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
}

  public class SamuraiMigration : MigrationBase
  {

      public override void Up()
      {
          if (!DataSettingsManager.IsDatabaseInstalled())
              return;

          // Cria a tabela com o nome ProductInfo e adiciona duas colunas, uma sendo do nome do produto e outra para preços
          Create.Table("ProductInfo")
              .WithColumn("ProductName").AsString(256).NotNullable()
              .WithColumn("ProductPrice").AsDecimal().NotNullable();

         
      }

      public override void Down()
      {
          // nothing
      }

  }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.